# How mstest.exe treat test DLL's config file?

Tags: unit-testing, configuration

I am a little confused about the way **mstest.exe** treat test DLL's app.config file.

Experiment project 1:

- A trivial non-test DLL. (It does nothing but read and print a app setting value from its own app.config file.)
- A main EXE file which calls the DLL to print its config value.

Experiment project 2:

- A unit test DLL which contains only one test method to read an app setting value from its own app.config file and write it to a file.
- I use mstest.exe to call the unit test DLL.

Result:

For 1. the DLL's config value is not printed.

For 2. the DLL's own config value is succesfully read and written to a file.

So, is there anything special about the **mstest.exe**?

Thanks.

---

I use SOS.dll to debug through my unit test DLL. I found that for each of the Unit Test DLL, a separate App Domain is created. And these App Domains are different from the one with the name **vstesthost.exe**. **I believe that configuration is specific to a App Domain**. Mstest.exe will create an App Domain for each of the test DLL and load its own config file into the App Domain, respectivly.

Hope someone could give a more confident explanation.

---

How to load a config file into a AppDomain?
-- to load a config file in to a AppDomain, use this:

> AppDomainSetup ad2setup = new
> AppDomainSetup();
>
> ad2setup.ConfigurationFile = @"config
> file path";

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is something special about mstest.exe. It will copy all references dlls to another directory and execute from there (I'm not sure why it does this, since tools like NCover simply run the tests from the bin folder). Because of this, you will have to configure anything else you wish to be copied besides the DLLs. The standard way to do this is by specifying the deployment items in the .testrunconfig file. You can do this by going to Test / Edit Test Run Configurations / Deployment. You can use the "Add File..." button to add the configuration file.